# How to evaluate the value of Javascript substring

Tags: javascript

How to evaluate the valueof Javascript substring.

I have a string like that. I wanted the filter out value the value of my title.

```
myStr = "<span title='Country' ></span>"
```

What I am trying here is

```
myStr.search(/title/i);
```

here I am geting index of title. IS there any substring method where I can get the value of title.

Comment: fist of all your `myStr` is assigned to an invalid string value (because of quotes)

Comment: @falinsky updated the question.

Comment: `myStr.match(/title='([^']*)'/)[1]` but beware of zalgo https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/351705

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not match HTML with a reg exp. I would parse it to DOM.

```js
const myStr = `<span title='Country' ><img src="classic/resources/images/country.png"/></span>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(myStr, "text/html");

console.log(doc.querySelector('span[title]').getAttribute('title'));
```